# Axios/Fetch does not set cookie in browser

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cookies, jwt

I am trying to authenticate user. The user sends Username and Password to express(using /login endpoint), the server returns the username if the entry is present in the database. Along with the username, a cookie is returned in headers, which contains json web token. The point is to set the jwt as a cookie in the client's browser. The system successfully authenticates the user and returns the text, but no cookie is set. Many similar questions have an approved answer of setting `withCredentials: true` for axios, but it does not seem to do the job for me. React is running on port 3001 and node on port 3000. Initially, I tried using fetch:

```
 fetch("http://localhost:3000/login", {
  body: JSON.stringify({
    Username: inputUsername,
    Password: inputPassword,
  }),
  credentials: "same-origin",
  method: "post",
  url: "http://localhost:3000",
  headers: new Headers({
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "access-control-allow-credentials": "true",
  }),
})
  .then((data) => data.json())
  .then((data) => setName("Hello, " + data.text));
```

but to no avail. Then, I switched to axios in hopes of more cookie support.

```
  axios
      .post("http://localhost:3000/login", {
        method: "post",
        Username: inputUsername,
        Password: inputPassword,
        withCredentials: true,
        exposedHeaders: ["set-cookie"],
      })
      .then((response) => setName("Hello, " + response.data.text));
  };
```

Again, it sends the text, but does not do set the cookie. Using Postman, I can see the cookie(interceptor is on): [image]
But nothing in the browser: [image]
Below is the entire node/express code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const cors = require("cors");
const { Pool } = require("pg");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");

app.use(cookieParser("MY SECRET"));

const pool = new Pool({
  user: "",
  host: "",
  database: "",
  password: "",
  port: "",
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());

pool.connect();
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "*",
    credentials: true,
  })
);

app.post("/login", async (req, res1) => {
  res1.header("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
  res1.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  console.log();
  await pool.query(
    'SELECT "userSession" FROM task2database WHERE "Username"=$1 AND "Password"=$2',
    [req.body.Username, req.body.Password],
    (err, res) => {
      if (res.rows.length > 0) {
        let options = {
          maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 15, // would expire after 15 minutes
          httpOnly: true, // The cookie only accessible by the web server
          signed: true, // Indicates if the cookie should be signed
        };
        res1.cookie(
          "token",
          jwt.sign({ user: req.body.Username }, "my_big_secret"),
          options
        );
        res1.set({ "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true });
        res1.json({ text: req.body.Username }).end();
      }
      console.log(res.rows);
    }
  );
  console.log("Response sent");
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server is up!");
});
```

Below is the entire React code:

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
function App() {
  const [name, setName] = React.useState("Waiting for login...");
  const [inputUsername, setUsername] = React.useState("");
  const [inputPassword, setPassword] = React.useState("");
  const username = (e) => {
    setUsername(e.target.value);
    console.log(inputUsername);
  };
  const password = (e) => {
    setPassword(e.target.value);
    console.log(inputPassword);
  };
  const getName = (e) => {
    console.log(inputUsername, inputPassword);
    e.preventDefault();
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:3000/login", {
        method: "post",
        Username: inputUsername,
        Password: inputPassword,
        withCredentials: true,
        exposedHeaders: ["set-cookie"],
      })
      .then((response) => setName("Hello, " + response.data.text));
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {name}

      <form onSubmit={getName}>
        <input
          onChange={username}
          type="text"
          name="username"
          placeholder="User"
        />
        <input
          onChange={password}
          type="text"
          name="password"
          placeholder="Pass"
        />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem: it sets the cookie on Postman, but not in browser. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Yes, google withCredentials in axios, but I faced other CORS issues for which I am going to ask a new question

Comment: Some time after comment here I was able to get it to work by setting up a `proxy` on `package.json`. I didn't even have to config the `cors` middleware